# i would like to have 3 default columns editable in guttenberg

Tags: themes

I would like to have 3 editable columns (25, 50, 25) like you can insert in Gutenberg, per default in every new page. How can I do this? If I give the columns to `page.php` they are not editable.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I understand you correctly, but is it templates you are looking for? https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-templates/

Comment: nearly; if i do array('core/columns') and 'page' i get the block with "choose layout" - how to say now "25/50/25" by program to be complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all this is [explained in detail in the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-templates/), just not exactly for this particular case.

To summarize:

- You want to set a "block template" for the post type "page".
- In this block template you want to have one columns block with 3 column blocks inside with widths of 25%, 50% and 25%

In code this looks like this:

```
function wpse_354875() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'page' );
    $post_type_object->template = [
        [
            'core/columns',
            [],
            [
                [
                    'core/column',
                    ['width'=>25],
                    []
                ],
                [
                    'core/column',
                    ['width'=>50],
                    []
                ],
                [
                    'core/column',
                    ['width'=>25],
                    []
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ];
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_354875' );
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried it with array like in the documentation but it does not work, maybe i did any mistake; this is working, so thanks a lot.

Comment: It should work with the long array syntax as well, this is just a matter of taste how you write it. But since there are a lot of nested arrays it is easy to make a mistake. Anyway if your problem is solved please accept this answer. Thank you!

Comment: Done :-) ; Maybe you can answer me to one more question; Any idea how to get the title in there? I noticed the titel is no block - i would like to get H1 (i already have) and the H1 should be the title, so if you edit it - the title is changed too...

Comment: Sorry, no. First, this would be an entirely different question, second there is no such feature right now, but your use case is being discussed, but no solution in sight right now.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are into the column you can add to the column array other blocks that you can identify. Below is another core/paragraph, but you could easily register your own block that grabs the title in an h1 tag (yourOwnBlocks/h1title in the below). I tried this with other block builder blocks and hooray that works too!! Thanks, Kraftner great tip.

```
                [ 'core/columns',
            [],
            [
                [
                    'core/column',
                    ['width'=>50],
                    [
                        ['core/paragraph',
                            [
                                'placeholder' => __( 'Add Description...', 'wp-rig' ),
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'core/column',
                    ['width'=>50],
                    [
                        ['yourOwnBlocks/h1title'],
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
```